# Can i prevent the keyboard to push things up when it's shown

Tags: android, ios, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am using sencha touch beta 3 version at the moment. I have a header bar(a panel docked to top) with buttons and title, and have a textarea on the other panel that takes space left. When i tap in the textarea, keyboard shows up and makes the header bar to scroll out of the screen. What i want is to have this header bar left in place. I would try to scroll it back to compensate the amount that keyboard pushes up to, but i wasn't able to implement that. Any help appreciated

Edit:
This issue is more relative to ios: on android keyboard pushes stuff up only if it (keyboard) overlaps the textarea, but on iphone keyboard always pushes stuff up.

Edit: if the textarea is thin, the header bar is not scrolled out on ios as well, but i need the textarea to be big enough, and the textarea scrolled if needed, not the headerbar.

Edit: i've implemented the header bar to move downward on keyboard showup and vise versa, but i'm facing issues with doing that simulatenously. Still hope to get some better way to do that, any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem having implemented the required screen natively (made a pg plugin to be able to create the screen from within javascript code)

Comment: Hi, Can you clarify more about your solution ? add some codes the plugin you used ?? thanx

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) attribute.

Adjust it so that your screen resizes when the keyboard pops up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, tested your suggestion on hts desire os 2.2: in portrait mode after tapping in the text area the keyboard shows and does not push anything up, and in landscape mode it still pushes header bar out(no matter what windowSoftInputMode is), but it seems to be okay since otherwise there would be no room to type text in. Testing the same on the ios 5 results in moving header bar in either portrait and landscape modes. I should've mentioned this issue is more relative to ios, will edit a question, thank you